# echoing out two dimensional associative arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I would like the data to be echoed out in this format

[0] - [name][description]
[1] - [name][description]
[2] - [name][description]

```
$options = array('guide_info' => $guide_info);

$guide_info = array( 'guide_name' => $guide_name, 
                     'guide_description' => $guide_description 
                   );
```

I created two foreach loops to try and echo out the name and description of each, like this:

```
foreach ($options as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($guide_info as $type => $info){
        $html .= $type . " " . $info . "\n";
    }
}
```

but I receive errors about invalid argument supplied for foreach() on the second loop.

Currently my print_r($options) shows

```
Array ( [guide_name] => f 
        [guide_description] => fff 
        [0] => Array ( 
                       [guide_name] => fsss 
                       [guide_description] => sssss 
                     ) 
       )
```

and my echo prints

```
guide_name fsss 
guide_description sssss 
guide_name fsss 
guide_description sssss 
guide_name fsss 
guide_description sssss
```

How would I be able to echo out the correct information that print_r is showing?

Comment: Isn't it displaying the information that print_r is showing? I mean guide_name is followed by fsss and guide_description is followed by sssss. Is that not right? How is it wrong?

Comment: Also I noticed you that above you created the `$options` array that uses `$guide_info` but you create `$guide_info` after it. I think you should move the `$guide_info` part above the `$options` part.

Comment: my echo is printing the second instants 3 times. It is skipping over the first one of f and fff

Comment: because you have it wrapped in a loop that has nothing to do with the second loop. for your second loop input, you should use the first loop's value

Comment: @khuderm is correct. Change `foreach ($guide_info as $type => $info)` to `foreach ($value as $type => $info)`

Comment: @Andrew I receive invalid argument supplied for foreach with that change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a recursive function to echo out the name and description values in the desired format.

```
function process_array($arr, $counter){
    foreach($arr as $key => $value){
        if(is_array($value)){
            process_array($value, ++$counter);
        }else{
            if($key == "guide_name"){
                echo "[" . $counter . "] - [" . $value . "][";
            }else{
                echo $value . "]<br />";
            }
        }
    }
}

// Here $options is your original array
process_array($options, 0);
```

**Output:**

```
[0] - [f][fff]
[1] - [fsss][sssss]
```

Comment: Thanks! It does what I need it to

Comment: @Sophie.J Glad I could help. Cheers! :-)

Comment: Hi! Just a quick question, how would I go about allowing the user to edit and delete specific options?

Comment: @Sophie.J It's a very different question. Please post a question on SO and give me its link here.

Answer (score 0):

```
$guide_info = array( 'guide_name' => 'guid name', 
                 'guide_description' => 'guid description',
               );
 $options = array('guide_info' => $guide_info); 

 foreach ($options as $key => $value) {
   foreach($value as $a => $b) {
echo $a," =",$b ;
 }
}
```

or for print_r

```
foreach ($options as $key => $value) {
    print_r($value) ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you putting the $guide_info in $options.If you want all the entries from $guide_info, you can do this-

```
    for($i = 0; $i < count($guide_info); $i++){
        $html .= $type . " " . $info . "\n";
    }
```

-> considering $guide_info is a multidimensional array like = array( [0] => 'guide_name' => $guide_name, 
                     'guide_description' => $guide_description)

If for some reason $guide_info IS important, I would suggest it to be an indexed array not assoc.. Hope you find the solution :)